# how to call a scope function before loading the template of a directive angualrjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootsrap popover https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ here is the documentation and in that I'm making a directive that basically does `<button popover-template="dynamicPopover.templateUrl" popover-title="{{dynamicPopover.title}}" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Popover With Template</button>` this. for some reason i had to overload the positioning function of the bootstrap to make it responsive so that i can make the popover display on the visible screen,

I made a Function

scope.getPopoverOnPosition = fucntion {....}

and in this function I am setting a scope.Position variable.

and in the template I'm doing `"<button popover-template="dynamicPopover.templateUrl" popover-title="{{dynamicPopover.title}}" type="button" popover-placement='{{position}}' class="btn btn-default">Popover With Template</button>"`
( specifying the direction gives an arrow pointed to the button relatively and also sets top and left positons of popover).
The problem is that the popover opens at first and it has no direction, then it blinks once and then there is the direction.

What I'm guessing is that fucntion is called later on and tmeplate is initialized before.. and when scope changes the change is then reflected as regenerate DOM. Is there any way to achieve this functionality without having a glich ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I think the problem is rather that you need to display the popover manually after setting the position rather than having it displayed automatically using trigger: 'manual'.

then define a mouseenter and mouseout callback. In the mouseenter callback set the position and show the popover and in the mouseout callback hide it:

```
$('...').on('mouseenter', function() {
    //set placement then...
    $(this).popover('show');
});

$('...').on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).popover('hide');
});
```

Like this the popover will not be automatically shown at the wrong position first but will only be displayed once the placement has been defined.